# Is there a better way than "gem ..., path: ..." for developing two gems simultaneously?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm currently developing a project and a gem at the same time. The project has this line in the Gemfile:

```
gem "my-gem", source: "http://my-gem-server"
```

But while developing, it needs to have this modification:

```
gem "my-gem", path: "../my-gem"
```

This means that I constantly have a change in my git repository that I need to be careful not to accidentally commit (which has happened more than a couple of times already.)

This is an absolute pain. Are there other common ways of accomplishing the same goal without needing temporary modifications to files?

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, I found a half-decent solution. I can ignore changes to `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` using this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile*
```

And when I actually need to commit an update to the Gemfile:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Gemfile*
```